# laravel passport optional authentication

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, middleware, laravel-passport

I have been using Laravel passport to response Api data, I want to response favorite status by user of product if a user login (token paste in header to validate with passport authentication Middleware). Is there a solution to determine if a user login or not without using Middleware "api" in route Api or separate Api url based user login and non user-login?

Comment: As I understand, you want a route to be accessible for authenticated and non-authenticated users. Why don't just use a public endpoint with no API middleware?

Comment: @Luciano the url is publicly accessible, and when a user login I want to response a status of products if they have already been added by user to their favorite list; but without middleware I could not check whether a user login (with api middleware). so that means I have to add another api url for user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that without middleware we can use Auth::guard('api') to validate the bearer token, so just add authorization header with bearer token and check user in controller using Auth::guard('api')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: for example you can write in your controller:  $user = Auth::guard('api')->user(); then you can check user->id or what you want.